# RegEx "\\" doen´t escape correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m trying to use RegEx to find a website using this RegEx:

```js
const RegEx = /h[\w]+[\:\/\/]+\w+[\.]+[\w\.=-]+[\.]+[\w]{2,3}[\w\/=-]+\\/g

Websites = document.children[0].innerHTML.match(RegEx)

console.log(Websites)

//["https://www.linuxfoundation.org/cookies\\","https://de.wikipedia.org\\",...]
```

It should match `"https://de.wikipedia.org\"`,because of the `\\` at the end, where the first \ escapes the other.

But when I execute this, it only logs websites with `"\\"` at the end.
It works on[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) but not in the browser.

It should find domains with `\` at the end!
I tried to use new RegExp and `[\\]` but both returned only `\\` at the end.

Comment: "But when I execute this, it only logs websites with `"\\"` at the end." - well, that's because your regex ends with `\\`, an escaped backslash?

Comment: `It should find domains with \ at the end. I tried to use new RegExp and [\\] but both returned only \\ at the end` both of your domains have `\ ` at the end, both match. Can you give an example which doesn't match but shouldn't?

Comment: It should match `"https://de.wikipedia.org\"`

Comment: `"https://de.wikipedia.org\"` isn't a valid string. You're misunderstanding the double backslash in the string. `"https://de.wikipedia.org\\"` does __not__ end with `\\ `, it ends with _one_  escaped `\ `.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But if I get the innerHtml of a document, there are some cases, where something like this happens: `href=\'https://discourse.nodered.org/u/877\'`. Do you know how I can get them with a RegEx?

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet that reproduces the issue -- so including the HTML, and using the toolbar button in the editor to insert a Stack Snippet. Make sure that when we run that snippet it produces the problem you describe.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to find all links through regex rather than just reading `href`s directly?

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to parse HTML with regex. That's usually not a great idea. Use a proper HTML parser, then you won't have any of these problems.

Comment: There are many things in your regular expression that doesn't make sense. For example `[\:\/\/]`. Square brackets defines a set of characters you want to match. There is no reason to have the same character more than one time in the set, and the characters used don't need to be escaped. Your  `[\:\/\/]` is equal to `[:/]`.

Comment: Was your regular expression supposed to match `"hX///////::://:::::/a...======....aaa=-=-=-=\\**"` because it do match.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression has many issues that need to be addressed before attempting to solve your problem.

You have:

```
const RegEx = /h[\w]+[\:\/\/]+\w+[\.]+[\w\.=-]+[\.]+[\w]{2,3}[\w\/=-]+\\/g
```

And it doesn't make sense.

`h[\w]+` matches the lowercase letter h followed by one or more a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ (underscore). I think you only wanted to match `http` and `https`, not `h0`, `h__42_B` or `hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh`.

`[\:\/\/]+`. Square brackets define a set of characters that you want to match. You have specified that colons and slashes should be included in the set. You have entered slashes twice. There is no reason to have the same character more than once in the set, and the characters used do not need to be escaped. Your `[\:\/\/]` is equal to `[:/]`. Thanks to the plus sign, it matches `://` but also `:::::::`, `/`, and `:::::://///////:/:/:/://:/:///:/://:/:/:/` which I don't think was the intention.

I assume you want to match `http://` or `https://`. The regular expression `https?://` is used for that. The question mark makes the `s` optional.

`\w+[\.]+[\w\.=-]+[\.]+[\w]{2,3}[\w\/=-]+` is very confusing. I think you are trying to match a domain name. You use `\w` which at first glance seems to work, as it is a character class that matches a-z, A-Z and 0-9. But it also matches underscores, which is not a valid character in domain names. You then use `[\.]+`. A dot literal must normally be escaped, but not inside a character class. Use either `\.` or `[.]`. I don't understand why you have the plus sign after it, which makes the expression match one or more dots. A domain name cannot have multiple dots in a row. `[\w\.=-]+` matches one or more a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscores, equal signs, and hyphens. Domain names cannot contain equal signs or underscores. With `[\w]{2,3}` I assume you are trying to match the top domain. It was many decades ago that a TLD could only consist of two or three characters. A top-level domain can consist of 1 to 63 characters. Your expression does match TLDs with more than three characters because you have `[\w\/=-]+` right after, but I don't think that was intentional.

Valid ASCII domain names can have a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and - (hyphens), and can be between 1 and 63 characters. The expression `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}` matches it.

A website usually has one or more subdomains under the top-level domain. By placing the expression in a group, it can match multiple instances: `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63 }` matches one or more subdomains followed by the top-level domain.

We now have `/https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}/` that matches the protocol (http or https), followed by `://` and then the domain name.

Now we can add your requirements. As I understand it from your examples, you want to match the string `https://de.wikipedia.org\`. Then we add `\\` to the end of the expression (because backslashes must be escaped) resulting in `/https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1.63}\\/`

You can test it bellow:

```js
const re = /https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\\/g

input.oninput = () => {
  output.replaceChildren(
    ...Array.from(input.value.matchAll(re)).map((m) => {
      const a = document.createElement('li');
      a.textContent = m;
      return a;
    })
  );
};
```

```css
output {
  white-space: pre;
}

textarea {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
Paste your example text below
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<ol id="output"></ol>
```

---

### Epilogue

And after all this I find in the comments that the text comes from innerHtml. If you have access to the document, or can open the debug console, there are much better ways to extract all the links in the document: `JSON.stringify(Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).map((a) => a.href))`

---

*Note! The domain match is not complete. There are rules for where the hyphen can be placed, and there are rules for how many subdomains there can be. With international domain names, almost any character from any script can be used. The example provided does not attempt to implement a full domain validation and does not support IDNs unless they are in punycode.*